# Inserting section titles in Reledmac from Right to Left in arabic text

Tags: polyglossia, arabic, reledmac

I'm typesetting an arabic text with Reledmac and Polyglossia. The problem is that the section titles with \eledsection command are inserted LTR. How can I insert the titles and number of sections right to left?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[series={A,B}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage[]{arabic} 
\setotherlanguages{farsi}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Arabic Typesetting}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\Afootnoterule}{\right@footnoterule\par}
\makeatother
\Xbhookgroup[A]{\RTL}
\Xbeforeinserting{\LTR}
\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\selectlanguage{arabic}
\pstart
\eledchapter{المقالة السابعة}
\pend
    \vspace*{7mm}
\pstart[\setRL]
\eledsection[]{\edtext{آ)}{\Afootnote{+ الباب الأول T /- L}}ذكر الأشياء التي يحتاج إلی معرفتها من أحب تركيب الأدوية علی ما ينبغي و‌تقدمة المعرفة ببسطها قبل تأليفها و‌تركيبها}
 \pend

\pstart[\setRL]
ينبغي لمن أراد \edtext{تركيب}{\Afootnote{التركيبT}} الأدوية علی ما ينبغي أن يكون عارفاً بقوة كل واحد منها و‌لا يقتصر في ذلك علی معرفة قواها التي هي بمنزلة الأجناس، كما فعل قوم من واضعي الكتب  فإنهم \edtext{وصفوا}{\Afootnote{وضعوا B}} في كتبهم أن هذا الدواء يسخن و‌هذا الدواء يبرد و‌\edtext{هذا}{\Afootnote{- B,L}} يجفف و‌هذا يرطب، بل \edtext{يعرف}{\Afootnote{نعرف T}} قواها علی التفصيل و‌التحديد \edtext{بأي مرتبة}{\Afootnote{- B,L}} و‌يعلم في أي درجة \edtext{يفعل}{\Afootnote{فعل L
/
جعل B
}} كل واحد منها \edtext{من واحدة واحدة}{\Afootnote{من واحدة واحدة من L,B}} هذه القوی و‌الأفعال. و‌ذلك أن من الأدوية ما يفعل الواحد \edtext{واحداً}{\Afootnote{فالواحد L,B}} من هذه الأفعال التي ذكرناها \edtext{فعلاً}{\Afootnote{T-}} خفياً جداً و‌منها ما يفعل ذلك فعلاً بيناً و‌منها ما يفعل ذلك فعلاً قوياً و‌منها ما يفعله فعلاً تاماً كاملاً و‌إذا كانت الأدوية تختلف \edtext{أفعالها}{\Afootnote{- L,B}} بحسب درجاتها فليس يكتفي الإنسان \edtext{بأن}{\Afootnote{أن L,B}} 
 \edtext{يعلم من}{\Afootnote{يعلم T}}
 أمرها أن هذا|
\ledsidenote{T-15v}
الدواء يسخن أو يبرد؛ بل قد \edtext{ينبغي}{\Afootnote{+«له أن يضيف إلی ذلك معرفة الحدّ فيه»T}} \edtext{أن}{\Afootnote{فـT}} يعلم كم من شأن الدواء|
\ledsidenote{L-3r}
أن يسخن أو يبرد.
 \pend
 \endnumbering
 \end{document}
```

Comment: \eledchapter is not allowed with article  class (as chapter is not allowed with article)

Comment: the problem is \eledsection command. if you eliminate \eledchapter or change the class, you'll see the problem likewise.

Comment: yes, but your minimal working example is not working... so it is not a good example, and I lost time with that.

Comment: you're right.I apologize.

Comment: some news about my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, your example is not a working example, as it call `\edledchapter` which is not provided with `article` class but only with `book` class. Please, next time provide a real MWE
2. Second point: in the last version of polyglossia, there is a but with `\edtext` inside arabic section. I don't know if you have the last version of polyglossia, but you can correct it using `\renewcommand{\theedtext}{edtxt@\the\c@edtext}`
3. Last but not least, your problem was caused by the unneeded `\Xbeforeinserting{\LTR}` which switch, before inserting, and so in the beginining of your `eledsection`, to LTR.

So here a working example.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[series={A,B}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[]{arabic}
\setotherlanguages{farsi}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Arabic Typesetting}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\Afootnoterule}{\right@footnoterule\par}
\renewcommand{\theedtext}{edtxt@\the\c@edtext}%
\Xbhookgroup[A]{\RTL}
\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\selectlanguage{arabic}
\pstart
\eledchapter{المقالة السابعة}
\pend
\chapter{المقالة السابعة}
\pstart[]
\eledsection[]{\edtext{آ)}{\Afootnote{+ الباب الأول T /- L}}ذكر الأشياء التي يحتاج إلی معرفتها من أحب تركيب الأدوية علی ما ينبغي و‌تقدمة المعرفة ببسطها قبل تأليفها و‌تركيبها}
 \pend
\section{\edtext{آ)}{\Afootnote{+ الباب الأول T /- L}}ذكر الأشياء التي يحتاج إلی معرفتها من أحب تركيب الأدوية علی ما ينبغي و‌تقدمة المعرفة ببسطها قبل تأليفها و‌تركيبها}
\pstart[]
ينبغي لمن أراد \edtext{تركيب}{\Afootnote{التركيبT}} الأدوية علی ما ينبغي أن يكون عارفاً بقوة كل واحد منها و‌لا يقتصر في ذلك علی معرفة قواها التي هي بمنزلة الأجناس، كما فعل قوم من واضعي الكتب  فإنهم \edtext{وصفوا}{\Afootnote{وضعوا B}} في كتبهم أن هذا الدواء يسخن و‌هذا الدواء يبرد و‌\edtext{هذا}{\Afootnote{- B,L}} يجفف و‌هذا يرطب، بل \edtext{يعرف}{\Afootnote{نعرف T}} قواها علی التفصيل و‌التحديد \edtext{بأي مرتبة}{\Afootnote{- B,L}} و‌يعلم في أي درجة \edtext{يفعل}{\Afootnote{فعل L
/
جعل B
}} كل واحد منها \edtext{من واحدة واحدة}{\Afootnote{من واحدة واحدة من L,B}} هذه القوی و‌الأفعال. و‌ذلك أن من الأدوية ما يفعل الواحد \edtext{واحداً}{\Afootnote{فالواحد L,B}} من هذه الأفعال التي ذكرناها \edtext{فعلاً}{\Afootnote{T-}} خفياً جداً و‌منها ما يفعل ذلك فعلاً بيناً و‌منها ما يفعل ذلك فعلاً قوياً و‌منها ما يفعله فعلاً تاماً كاملاً و‌إذا كانت الأدوية تختلف \edtext{أفعالها}{\Afootnote{- L,B}} بحسب درجاتها فليس يكتفي الإنسان \edtext{بأن}{\Afootnote{أن L,B}}
 \edtext{يعلم من}{\Afootnote{يعلم T}}
 أمرها أن هذا|
\ledsidenote{T-15v}
الدواء يسخن أو يبرد؛ بل قد \edtext{ينبغي}{\Afootnote{+«له أن يضيف إلی ذلك معرفة الحدّ فيه»T}} \edtext{أن}{\Afootnote{فـT}} يعلم كم من شأن الدواء|
\ledsidenote{L-3r}
أن يسخن أو يبرد.
 \pend
 \endnumbering
 \end{document}
```